# Getting Data Out of a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This has been bothering me for ages and I tried everything and I cannot get it to work.

Here is my function currently

```
   function example1() {
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
      data=(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
     }
  xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
```

I would like to be able to get "data" out of that function that I can then in another function return some regex on AND I would like to be able to make "url" dependent on user input

I hope someone can help me, this is driving me extremely crazy.

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to change the third parameter, the **async** flag from

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true)
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false)
```

A common mistake is to think this is a scoping problem since if you set debugging messages within the xmlhttp.onload = function() {...}, it works within the callback while nothing happens outside the callback.

It turns out this is actually a timing problem because if **async** is set to **true** (the default), the debugging messages outside of the onload callback run before the callback gets executed.

Answer (score -1):

XmlHttpRequest doesn't work across domain, so if a user, say, submits http://google.com, it won't work.  However, if you want to get data from your own site, and have them input a url from your own site, then the HTML of url would be included in

```
xmlhttp.responseHtml;
```

Comment: sorry that is not myy problem. "I would like to be able to get "data" out of that function that I can then in another function return some regrex on AND I would like to be able to make "url" dependent on user input"

Comment: Oh sorry about that.  To get user input, lets say you have a var url, then change it to this:
var data = example1(url);
So instead of saying
data=(xmlhttp.responseText);
say
return xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: I'm still having trouble. I have found another reason why I can't continue so I'm giving up on the whole idea (for now)

Thanks anyway